# How to "linearize" a term of the form $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( m \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} \right)$ in a nonlinear PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, linearization, mathematical-biology

I am currently studying the following nonlinear PDE model for cells migrating under the influence of diffusion and chemotaxis:

\begin{align}
       \hspace{2cm} \frac{\partial m}{\partial t} & = \frac{\partial^2 m}{\partial x^2} - \chi \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(m \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} \right) &&  \hspace{2cm} (1)   \\[5pt]
       \hspace{2cm} \frac{1}{a} \frac{\partial c}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2} + m - c && \hspace{2cm} (2)
\end{align}

Here $m(x,t)$ and $c(x,t)$ denote the concentrations of cells and chemoattractant (a chemical to which the cells are attracted), respectively, and $a,\chi$ are positive constants. Let $(\overline{m},\overline{c})$ denote a homogeneous steady state of (1)-(2), that is,

1. $(\overline{m},\overline{c})$ is a solution of (1)-(2), and
2. $ \dfrac{\partial \overline{m}}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial \overline{c}}{\partial t} = 0$ and $ \dfrac{\partial^2 \overline{m}}{\partial x^2} = \dfrac{\partial^2 \overline{c}}{\partial x^2} = 0$.

My goal is to now linearize (1)-(2) about the homogeneous steady state $(\overline{m},\overline{c})$ so that I can determine conditions under which the HSS is unstable. The only nonlinear term in the model is the chemotaxis term $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big(m \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} \big)$.

**My question.** How do I "linearize" the term $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big(m \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} \big)$ ?

I have been consulting *Mathematical Models in Biology* by Leah-Edelstein Keshet as a reference, where in section 11.4 the author studies a reaction-diffusion system of the form

\begin{align*}
   \frac{\partial C_1}{\partial t} = D_1 \frac{\partial C_1}{\partial x^2} + R_1(C_1,C_2)  \\[5pt]
   \frac{\partial C_2}{\partial t} = D_2 \frac{\partial C_2}{\partial x^2} + R_2(C_1,C_2).  \\[5pt]
\end{align*}

Given a solution $(C_1,C_2)$ of the RD-system, the author defines inhomogeneous perturbation terms $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ by
\begin{align*}
    C_1'(x,t) := C_1(x,t) - \overline{C}_1 \\[2pt]
    C_1'(x,t) := C_1(x,t) - \overline{C}_1 \\[2pt]
\end{align*}

and then linearizes the system by writing the Taylor series expansions for $R_1(\overline{C}_1,\overline{C}_2)$ and $R_2(\overline{C}_1,\overline{C}_2)$ about $(\overline{C}_1,\overline{C}_2)$, and then dropping the nonlinear terms:
\begin{align*}
  R_1(\overline{C}_1,\overline{C}_2) &= R_1(\overline{C}_1 + C_1', \overline{C}_2 + C_2')  \\[4pt]
      & = R_1(\overline{C}_1, \overline{C}_2) + \frac{\partial R_1}{\partial C_1}(\overline{C}_1, \overline{C}_2) C_1' + \frac{\partial R_1}{\partial C_2}(\overline{C}_1, \overline{C}_2) C_2' + \text{H.O.T.}  \\[10pt]
    R_2(\overline{C}_1,\overline{C}_2) &= R_2(\overline{C}_1 + C_1', \overline{C}_2 + C_2')  \\[4pt]
    & = R_2(\overline{C}_1, \overline{C}_2) + \frac{\partial R_2}{\partial C_1}(\overline{C}_1, \overline{C}_2) C_1' + \frac{\partial R_2}{\partial C_2}(\overline{C}_1, \overline{C}_2) C_2' + \text{H.O.T.}
\end{align*}

Dropping the higher-order terms and using the fact that $R_1(\overline{C}_1,\overline{C}_2) = R_1(\overline{C}_1,\overline{C}_2) = 0$ (which follows immediately from the fact that $(\overline{C}_1,\overline{C}_2)$ is a HSS) leads to the following linear PDEs for the perturbations:
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\partial C_1'}{\partial t} = D_1 \frac{\partial C_1'}{\partial x^2} + a_{11} C_1' + a_{12} C_2'  \\[5pt]
  \frac{\partial C_2'}{\partial t} = D_2 \frac{\partial C_2'}{\partial x^2} + a_{21} C_1' +   a_{22} C_2'  
\end{align*}

where $a_{ij} := \frac{\partial R_i}{\partial C_j}(\overline{C}_1,\overline{C}_2)$. I am not sure if this method is applicable to equations (1)-(2) however because the term $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(m \frac{\partial c}{\partial x})$ is not of the form $f(m,c)$. How then would I go about "linearizing" this term?

Comment: Can't you just plug in $m(x,t) = \overline{m} + m'(x,t)$ and $c(x,t) = \overline{c} + c'(x,t)$, multiply everything out, and drop any terms that are nonlinear in $m'$ and/or $c'$?

Comment: @HansLundmark: I don't quite understand. Could you show me explicitly?

Comment: Well, to begin with, what do you get if you just expand? $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \bigl( \overline{m} + m'(x,t) \bigr) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \bigl( \overline{c} + c'(x,t) \bigr) \right) = \quad \cdots \quad?$$

Comment: Oh, ok. We get $(mc_x)_x = m_x c_{x} + m c_{xx} = m_x' c_{x} + (\overline{m} + m') c_{xx} = m_x' c_x + \overline{m} c_{xx} + m' c_{xx}$. Now I see that $m' c_{xx}$ is small when the perturbation $m'$ is small. But is $m_x' c_{x}$ necessarily small when $m'$ is small?

Comment: I think linearization in this context involves making the assumption that not only $m'$ and $c'$ are sufficiently small, but also their derivatives (as many as are necessary), to justify dropping the terms $m'_x c'_x$ and $m' c'_{xx}$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the help!